# Remove duplicates, group items for dropdown list

Tags: .net, linq, razor, .net-core

In my MVC cshtml page, I have a set of records passed in via Model.  I want to take the values in one column and display the unique values in a dropdown/select.  I'm getting an error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Grouping System.String,VrsDataModel.Data.AuditItem]' to type 'VrsDataModel.Data.AuditItem'...
```

My code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="userSearch">
    <option></option>
    @foreach (AuditItem ai in Model.GroupBy(ai => ai.UserLogin))
    {
        <option value="@ai.UserLogin.ToName()">@ai.UserLogin.ToName()</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Figured it out.  My Model contains a list, have to get the first item in each group?   Model.GroupBy(m => m.UserLogin.ToName()).Select(g => g.First()))

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the "ai" variable isn't of type "AuditItem". Look at the definition of the GroupBy method (I'm assuming that's the "Linq" method). It returns type "`IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`", so "ai" will be "`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`", where TKey will be whatever the type of the "UserLogin" property is, and TElement is whatever type "Model" is. You can use "ai.Key" to get the grouped value, and you can enumerate the grouped items by iterating the contents of "ai".

If you only want the distinct values, try "`Model.Select(x=>x.UserLogin.ToName()).Distinct()`".